# LiveSDK ( LiveConnect Api ) or SkyDrive Api for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am not sure which assembly is the correct one to use for Windows Phone. The below Url shows an example of using LiveSDK.

http://nikovrdoljak.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/backup-your-windows-phone-isolated-storage-data-to-skydrive-using-live-connect-api/

I have added `Microsoft.Live` and `Microsoft.Live.Control` for the References

Code:

```
client.Session.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected
```

Error:

```
'Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectSession' does not contain a definition for 'Status'
and no extension method 'Status' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectSession'
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Code:

```
private LiveConnectClient client;
private void UploadPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (client == null || client.Session == null || client.Session.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must sign in first.");
    }
    else
    {
        client.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(GetFolderProperties_Completed);
        // If you put photo to folder it becomes album.
        client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders,albums");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for pointing out the diff. So, in the Upload Function, do I need to check this:  client.Session.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected ?   The sign-in checking is ok now :e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected

Answer (score 1):

So it's fairly obvious the `LiveConnectSession` doesn't have the Status property. Why do you keep thinking it has it then?

In the example code he's using the `Status` property of the `LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs` class, not the `LiveConnectSession`.

A recommendation for re-reading the basics seems in order here.

Comment: Thank for pointing out the diff. So, in the Upload Function, do I need to check this: client.Session.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected ? The sign-in checking is ok now :e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected

Comment: That's completely up to you. It's your program, not mine.

Comment: Thanks. My question is How do I check if my session or connection  is still alive. This one not working :client.Session.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected . This way, I can be sure to do something before uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Live SDk contain the SignIn Button and LiveConnet DLL. To connect to SKyDrive, it is required to use SignIn Button to sign in. Once it is connected, you can use the return session to create a LiveConnectClient.It is good practise to check if the session is still alive before doing any tasks on the SkyDrive.